Return list of sheet names from another google sheets workbook (file)
i'm trying to find a way to list all sheet names inside one googlesheets workbook, into another google sheets workbook.
So let's say i have two files:
main.gsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kElZpNQtsHQQBFA3jCcMj_pjtyWEw9WQafxObP8GXEs/edit?usp=sharing
data.gsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yzp4CJist1DTQOm8rRoBcD125pChorMmuY7ZnRm82-k/edit?usp=sharing
data.gsheet contains sheets named "a", "b", and "c".
i want main.gsheet to pull the names "a", "b", "c" from data.gsheet, along with any future additions or changes to data.gsheet's sheet names.
found some appscript for pulling sheet names from the SAME current/active workbook, but having trouble pulling from ANOTHER workbook.

SUGGESTED SOLUTION
You should be able to achieve what you'd like with openById(id) or openByUrl(url).
This is an example script:
const myFunction = () => {
  var ds = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1yzp4CJist1DTQOm8rRoBcD125pChorMmuY7ZnRm82-k").getSheets();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main");
  var op = [];
  ds.forEach(sh => {
    op.push([sh.getName()]);
  });
  ss.getRange(2, 2, op.length).setValues(op);
}


Make sure to go to Extensions > Apps Script on the Main spreadsheet and run the code from there.

OUTPUT

UPDATE
If you would like the script to run automatically, here's a method that I have in mind:
Set up An installable change trigger that runs when a user modifies the structure of a spreadsheet itself—for example, by adding a new sheet or removing a column.
This is the updated script:
const myFunction = () => {
  var ms = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1kElZpNQtsHQQBFA3jCcMj_pjtyWEw9WQafxObP8GXEs").getSheetByName("Main");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var op = [];
  ss.forEach(sh => {
    op.push([sh.getName()]);
  });
  ms.getRange(2, 2, op.length).setValues(op);
}


Note: The script needs to be put on the Data spreadsheet and run at least once since that's where the installable On change trigger will be set. It can be set up by going to the Triggers tab of Google Apps Script.

This is what it should look like:

REFERENCE

Event-driven triggers


thanks- but i get this error message: Error
Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (line 2).

I see that you've tried running the script as a custom function by putting in =myFunction() on a cell. Instead, you may go to Extensions > Apps Script and run the script from there.

ok i see how it works.  but does that mean every time a new sheet is added to "data", "main" won't automatically show this change and i need to RUN the script each time?

Yes. There are ways to make the script run automatically, like using Installable Triggers. However, that wasn't included in my answer since it was only stated that i want main.gsheet to pull the names "a", "b", "c" from data.gsheet, along with any future additions or changes to data.gsheet's sheet names. and doesn't explicitly imply that it's a requirement.

Kindly check my updated answer on how to make the script run whenever a new sheet is created on the Data spreadsheet. Let me know if you have any questions, and I'll be keen to assist in any way I can!
